# How can I change the stack order of widgets inside a row widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I have noticed that when I add a row widget wrapped with an aligned widget and set its alignment to alignment.centre right, and then add 2 container widgets inside the row widget, the second widget is always above the first one.
Is there a way I can change the order in which the widgets are placed over each other? I'm using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets)
package to stack the container widgets in this manner

```
child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: RowSuper(
              children: <Widget>[
                //
                // writing container ---------------------------------------
                Container(
                  color: Color(0xFF313340),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6026,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3739,
                ),
                //
                // image container -----------------------------------------
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3864,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4843,
                ),
              ],
              innerDistance: -97.5,
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

The children property is a list, so you can generate a list with your desired widgets and add a .reverse.

```
void main() {
   List<String> list= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

   print("Normal list: $list");
   // Result: Normal list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   print("Reversed list: ${list.reversed}");
   // Result: Reversed list: (5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
}
```

From what I understand of your question this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

We can the source code for that package on github, and this is how RowSuper lays out children:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < _children!.length; i++) {
      double width = maxChildWidth[i];

      BoxConstraints innerConstraints = BoxConstraints(
          maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight, maxWidth: width, minWidth: fill ? width : 0.0);

      var child = _children![i];
      child.layout(innerConstraints, parentUsesSize: true);
      maxChildHeight = max(maxChildHeight, child.size.height);
    }
```

It looks pretty straightforward. Children are laid out in the order that they are provided, so I suppose your only option would be to change the order in which you're providing them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies
I figured out this one, it worked best for me by simply using `invert: true`
here's the code if anyone has the same problem

```
child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: RowSuper(
          children: <Widget>[
            //
            // writing container ---------------------------------------
            Container(
              color: Color(0xFF313340),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6026,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3739,
            ),
            //
            // image container -----------------------------------------
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3864,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4843,
            ),
          ],
          innerDistance: -97.5,
          invert: true, //The line that was added <=====================================
        ),
      )
```